# Edit existing Outlook invite to be an invite to an existing Teams meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

Background: I'll host a small conference at work, for which I sent an invite with the program etc. in Outlook. There is also a Teams team for the conference-related things (e.g. sharing the program). The conference will be physical, but we decided to let people join also remotely. I would like to update the Outlook invite to contain a link to the call and also have that meeting in the team General channel.

I can add a Teams call to the Outlook invite, and I can schedule a call in Teams. But how do I make it the same call?

- I tried scheduling two meetings and then editing the link in the Outlook invite, but it complains that the invite is not the same as what is written in the email body.
- I can also just add a link in the Outlook invite body, but then Outlook doesn't show the "join" button in the calendar for that meeting.

Comment: Why didn't you add a teams meeting to one invite, copy this link and update another invite with it? Normally, there is a button **Click here to join the meeting** under the meeting email if you are using **Teams Meeting**.

Comment: @Ivan_Wang, that's exactly what I tried, and Outlook told me that the meeting in the body is not the same as in the invite. How I understand it is that the invite I create in Outlook is actually two distinct things in one: a calendar meeting, with an option to join via Teams, and an invite email containing a link to that meeting in the body. I can edit the email body, but that doesn't change the meeting. Outlook is smart to check that the email body doesn't conflict with the calendar meeting, to prevent confusion.

Comment: Hence I cannot simply edit the email body to replace one Teams link with another. I wonder if there is some other option hidden somewhere in Outlook.